# How can I find the locator codes for neighboring Maidenhead grids?

Tags: php, algorithm, gps

I'm trying to create map with tiles around a single [Maidenhead grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidenhead_Locator_System), however I don't know how to calculate the 9 grids around a single maidenhead grid.

I have, for example, locator `JO22OI60KE` which I calculate on given coordinates and I would like the other (green in the example) nine locators around this grid.

[image: Maidenhead grid]

I've looked around a lot but the implementations I see all focus on getting a Maidenhead out of a single latitude and longitude. Within [a extended "square"](https://enacademic.com/pictures/enwiki/77/Maidenhead_Locator_System_explained.svg) I can calculate its neighbors but once you are on the edges (so to say, touching a new sub square) it goes beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Shockingly, there's not a builtin for this. Have you looked up a reference implementation? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've looked around a lot but they all focus on getting a Maidenhead out of a single latitude and longitude. Within a extended "square" [link](https://enacademic.com/pictures/enwiki/77/Maidenhead_Locator_System_explained.svg) i can calculate it's neighbors but once you are on the edges(so to say, touching a new sub square) it goes beyond my capabilities

Comment: Well if you're in grid `(0,0)` and subgrid `(9,9)` the subgrid one up would be `(0,1) (9,0)`, one over would be `(1,0) (0,9)`, and up _and_ over would be `(1,1) (0,0)`. The only differences arre that the grids are numbered `a-x` instead of `0-9`, and there are a few more levels of grids. Though I thinks it's dumb and confusing that the grids alternate between alpha and numerical and even the alpha grids have inconsistent bases.

Comment: Anyhow, it was an interesting problem and there really wasn't much useful code I could find in _any_ language, so I wrote a quick and dirty lib that can read/transform/write Maidenhead coordinates basef on the Wikipedia article about it: https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/maidenhead Count your lucky stars that I was left unsupervised today.

Comment: That is really impressive, thank you very much! Basically offsetting the alpha fields as numeric as well results in the desired effect, thank you for the explanation. I will send you an email (via your website) once i have something up and running in a few months. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sammitch: I reopened the question, if you'd like to convert your comments to an answer.

Comment: @JonEricson ughhh _fine_. I'll write a thing and get some points if I _have_ to.

Comment: @Sammitch: Thank you! Your answer is a lot more extensive than I expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cliff's Notes for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidenhead_Locator_System

- Every pair characters in an MLS coordinate is a cell in a grid, with each subsequent grid contained inside the previous.
- Each pair alternates between alphabetical and numerical of bases: 18, 10, 24, `GOTO 10` for as much precision as you feel like.
- While the spec *says* case is important, it's not really.

So we can decompose `JO22OI60KE` to `(J,O), (2,2), (O,I), (6,0), (K,E)` to `(10,15), (2,2), (15,9), (6,0), (11,5)`.

The approach I took in [the lib I wrote](https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/maidenhead) [included below] was to decompose the coordinates into their numeric pairs, and then apply any transformations [represented by a set of offsets] starting from the least significant to most while keeping a "carry" pair.

However, it would probably be simpler to just multiply everything out to an `259,200 x 259,200` [`18*10*12*10*12`] grid, do simple math to transform, and then use more math to reformat back to an MLS coordinate. This would also greatly simplify converting to/from lat/lng as that's just more simple math.

Live and learn. The first iteration of something is usually only good at teaching you how you should have done it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

### Code:

Included because links can die which renders the answer useless. Please do check [the repo](https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/maidenhead) in case there are PRs/changes. Also listed on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/maidenhead),

```
class Coordinate {
    const ENC_FIELD        = 0;
    const ENC_SQUARE       = 1;
    const ENC_SUBSQUARE    = 2;

    const ENC_MAX = [
        self::ENC_FIELD => 18,
        self::ENC_SQUARE => 10,
        self::ENC_SUBSQUARE => 24
    ];

    const ENC_CHARS = [
        self::ENC_FIELD => 'abcdefghijklmonpqr',
        self::ENC_SQUARE => '0123456789',
        self::ENC_SUBSQUARE => 'abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwx'
    ];

    // The spec only covers the first 4 pairs, the 4th pair "extended subsquare" uses the same encoding as "square"
    // Non-standard extensions of the spec are to be implemented as extensions of this class.
    protected static $encode_order = [ self::ENC_FIELD, self::ENC_SQUARE, self::ENC_SUBSQUARE, self::ENC_SQUARE ];

    protected $pairs = [];
    protected $precision;

    public function __construct($pairs) {
        foreach($pairs as $pair) {
            $this->addPair($pair);
        }
        $this->precision = count($pairs);
    }

    public function transform($offsets) {
        $offset_count = count($offsets);
        $pair_count = $this->precision;
        $encoding_count = count(static::$encode_order);

        if( $offset_count > $pair_count ) {
            throw new \Exception('Number of offsets greater than the number of coordinate pairs');
        }

        $carry = [0, 0];
        $new_pairs = [];

        // process the smallest offset first so that we don't have to specify a full array all the time
        // and also so that carries can be efficiently handled
        for( $o=1,$c=$pair_count; $o<=$c; $o++ ) {
            $offset_index = $offset_count - $o;
            $pair_index   = $this->precision - $o;

            $cur_pair = $this->pairs[$pair_index];
            if( $offset_index < 0 ) {
                $cur_offset = $carry;
            } else {
                $cur_offset = $offsets[$offset_index];

                // apply carry
                $cur_offset = [
                    $cur_offset[0] + $carry[0],
                    $cur_offset[1] + $carry[1]
                ];
            }

            $new_lat = $this->rollover($cur_pair->lat + $cur_offset[0], static::ENC_MAX[static::$encode_order[$pair_index]]);
            $new_lng = $this->rollover($cur_pair->lng + $cur_offset[1], static::ENC_MAX[static::$encode_order[$pair_index]]);

            $carry = [ $new_lat[1], $new_lng[1] ];
            $new_pair = new Pair( $new_lat[0], $new_lng[0] );
            array_unshift($new_pairs, $new_pair);
        }
        return new static($new_pairs);
    }

    public function toString() {
        $output = '';
        for( $i=0; $i<$this->precision; $i++ ) {
            $output .= $this->encodeAs($this->pairs[$i]->lat, static::$encode_order[$i]);
            $output .= $this->encodeAs($this->pairs[$i]->lng, static::$encode_order[$i]);
        }
        return $output;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->toString();
    }

    protected function rollover($value, $base) {
        if( $value < 0 ) {
            $result = ($value % $base) ? $base + ($value % $base) : 0;
            $carry = (int)ceil(abs($value) / $base) * -1;
        } else if( $value >= $base ) {
            $result = $value % $base;
            $carry = (int)floor($value / $base);
        } else {
            $result = $value;
            $carry = 0;
        }

        return [ $result, $carry ];
    }

    protected function addPair(Pair $pair) {
        $this->pairs[] = $pair;
    }

    public static function fromString($input, $pad=true) {
        $pairs = [];
        $raw_pairs = array_map('str_split', str_split($input, 2));
        for( $i=0,$c=count($raw_pairs); $i<$c; $i++ ) {
            if( ! isset(static::$encode_order[$i]) ) {
                throw new \Exception("No decoding specified for pair index $i");
            }
            $encoding = static::$encode_order[$i];
            $pairs[] = new Pair(
                self::decodeAs($raw_pairs[$i][0], $encoding),
                self::decodeAs($raw_pairs[$i][1], $encoding)
            );
        }
        if( $pad ) {
            for( $c=count(static::$encode_order); $i<$c; $i++ )
            $pairs[] = new Pair(0,0);
        }
        return new static($pairs);
    }

    public static function decodeAs($str, $encoding) {
        $value = strpos(self::ENC_CHARS[$encoding], strtolower($str));
        if( $value === false ) {
            throw new \Exception("Invalid character $str for encoding $encoding");
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public static function encodeAs($int, $encoding) {
        return self::ENC_CHARS[$encoding][$int];
    }
}

class Pair {
    protected $lat, $lng;

    public function __construct($lat, $lng) {
        $this->lat = $lat;
        $this->lng = $lng;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        throw new Exception('Immutable');
    }
}
```